# xdebug breakpoints work but step over does not

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I have installed Xampp on Windows (Well actually both xampp and wamp but both have the same problem), and enabled xdebug. I have installed the latest eclipse for php with pdt included. The breakpoints are working correctly however if I press f6 or f5 the current line does not get updated, the variables change as if I had stepped to the following line but the highlighted line remains the same. Any ideas?

I attach some screenshots to make it easier to understand:

Breakpoint works:

[image]

I press f6, lineno and $a changes in the 'Debug' and 'Variables' window:

[image]

I press f6 again:

[image]

I tried updating to the latest xdebug but the same thing happens.

Comment: Trying using [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/); it works perfectly with the latest version of xdebug and php5.5

Comment: Have you MakeGood plugin installed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is problem in Eclipse SR1. You should switch back to R (SR0) release, next you can install PDT 3.3.1 from marketplace.

See also [bug report on bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445903#c3)

**Edit:**

Problem is fixed in nightly builds: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.4-nightly/

**Edit 2:**

We released new stable (3.3.2) version with fix for this problem. You can find it on marketplace or in this update site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.3.2/

Answer (score 4):

1. Goto Eclipse->Help->Install New Software
2. Work with: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.3.2/ (this worked for me)
3. Alternative: You might want to use the latest stable update site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest/
4. [If not already existing]: click (Add) & give a name like "PDT" in order to add the upgrade site.
5. Type "PDT" and tick checkbox for "PHP Development Tools (PDT)"
6. Accept the license stuff and upgrade PDT.
7. Restart Eclipse