# Xdebug/Eclipse PDT doesn't show progess while debugging

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I've gotten my reinstallation of current Eclipse/XAMPP/XDebug the example and a PHP program I wrote. When I Debug as CLI, the green progress bar over the first line appears. When I hit F6 (Step Over) the green bar doesn't move but I notice the execution taking place because variable values are being set.  After 20 clicks I can see I stepped INTO a function (!!!) for some values are set. All I need is for Eclipse and/or Xdebug to tell me what line I am on.  Is there a setting I have missed?

```
Windows 7
XAMPP 1.8.3
PHP 5.5.15.
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_autostart=Off
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Using xDebug and Eclipse the instruction pointer is not moving, but actions are taking place while debugging. I debug as PHP web application. Did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It works with a different version/package of Eclipse for me: Eclipse Helios SR2 PHP, available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Helios/SR2). I tested Luna and Mars releases as well, but none of them worked. I am using this setup for PHP development and xDebug in Eclipse on Windows7 64bit:

- WAMP 2.5 64bit (Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12)
- Eclipse Helios SR2 for PHP Win64
- xDebug DLL 2.2.5 for PHP 5.5 VC11 TS (threadsafe) 64bit

The debug instruction pointer is moving correctly while stepping over instructions now.

Helios Release of Eclipse is actually not up to date and only supports until PHP 5.3. But if this is negligible this setup is a solution. 
I also tested the XAMP package and different versions of xDebug DLL (for older php releases, compiled with VC9 etc.) but it doesn't make a difference. xDebug does overall not seem to be the problem here, as xDebug support worked in all cases and was evident via phpinfo(). It might be an Eclipse Bug.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this as a bug to Eclipse but they are saying it's not an Eclipse problem, but an XDebug problem. It was a weasel-worded answer. I don't believe them. Responses from the Xdebug mailing say it's an Eclipse problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with latest Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, due changes in debug component. We fixed this in PDT 3.3.2 service release.

[xdebug breakpoints work but step over does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067892/xdebug-breakpoints-work-but-step-over-does-not)