# While debugging PHP, the visual of the debugged line won't change to the next in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am trying to install and debug PHP on ubuntu. I have installed Eclipse with PDT, install Apache and PHP, downloaded and install Xdebug and configured it.

I have created a simple one file project and I am successful in debugging it. Breakpoints get stops and step through also works.

The only problem is that Eclipse does not change the marked line after jumping to the next breakpoint. The previous line is still marked even though the execution is on the other line. The same happens when pressing F8 for the next breakpoint and F6 for stepping.

The debugging itself is advancing as you can see in the debug window. The line number is changing accordingly. Only the visual is not. 
Any ideas ?

[image]

php.ini configuration:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [xdebug breakpoints work but step over does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067892/xdebug-breakpoints-work-but-step-over-does-not)

You need latest PDT-nightly or downgrade to luna 4.4.0