# Eclipse PDT + xdebug: step through code broken

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I'm using PHP 5.6.2 with xdebug 2.2.5 and Eclipse 4.4.1 with PDT 3.3.1. I'm trying to setup the debugger (xdebug) on a local server (localhost) and something appears to be broken.

When I start a debugging session eclipse switches to the debug perspective and stops at first line (as checked in config). The problem is that although the debugger (in debug window) seems to follow the execution as I step through code (it shows code lines as it advances), the window below that opens the source file and shows the code remains on the first position like/breakpoint it hits. It seems to be disconnected from the debugger...

Does anyone knows how to fix the problem ? Is it me, or there is a bug in this ? It used to work with older php/eclipse combination.  I've upgraded php to 5.6 in between, as well as all it's dependencies. Same for eclipse. It's hard to pin point the issue at this point.

I'm using nginx with php-fpm.

Xdebug config in php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [xdebug breakpoints work but step over does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067892/xdebug-breakpoints-work-but-step-over-does-not)

You need latest PDT-nightly or downgrade to luna 4.4.0