# Step over(F6) not showing line by line

Tags: debugging, eclipse-juno, eclipse-pdt

Please see attached screenshot. I think any configuration is wrong in debugging. Can anybody guide me how to resolve this issue ? I am using eclipse juno on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of: [Eclipse PDT + xdebug: step through code broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457139/eclipse-pdt-xdebug-step-through-code-broken)

Please install PDT 3.3.2 (for example from Eclipse Marketplace [Help -> Eclipse MarketPlace] or wait 2 weeks for Eclipse Luna SR2 ;)