# How to make Eclipse debugging automatically jump to line being debugged

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

When debugging PHP code, my Eclipse (Luna) doesn't automatically move to the line currently being debugged.

Is there a configuration setting that will make it so that the debugger automatically moves to the line currently debugging? For me, when I hit Step Over it moves to the next line in the "Debug" window but the source code view jumps to my breakpoint instead. Then I have to scroll to the currently debugging line of code until I hit Step Over again, which brings me back to the breakpoint.

What's strange is that I can click on any of the other "Debugger" linenos in the top left window and it will jump to the spot in the source, but if I click on the top one, the one I want to go to, it goes to the break point, even though the lineno is not the lineno of the breakpoint - I'm past that break point and don't need to keep looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, see also [xdebug breakpoints work but step over does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067892/xdebug-breakpoints-work-but-step-over-does-not)

Just upgrade to Luna SR2 and everything will be fine ;)