# Eclipse PHP code assist stopped working with PDT 3.3.2

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I was using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 with PDT 3.2.0. Code assist (`cmd+click` on function/variables navigation, documentation on mouse hover) was working fine.

I wanted to use XDebug to debug PHP and I've read in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215885/513570 that PDT needed to be updated to 3.3.2.

I updated to 3.3.2 and code assist stopped working. I've read lots of places where they say to review `.buildpath` and `.project` to make sure they are correct. Also tried to clean and rebuild project and remove file in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2` and rebuild project again but nothing works.

Is it possible to make PDT 3.3.2 work with code assist? How?

**.buildpath file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="projectname/public"/>
</buildpath>
```

**.project file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>projectname</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.dltk.core.scriptbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating to eclipse 4.5.1 and PDT 3.6